# Nivo Slider navigation stylisation issue

Tags: jquery, css, slider, nivo-slider

So I have a custom Nivo Slider theme called DotsAndDashes, and I've got a couple issues with it I'm struggling to resolve via the theme's CSS sheet.

The first, as suggested above, concerns the navigation arrows whereby the nextNav was this morning facing the wrong way. I've had a tinker with the CSS, and it's now as such:

```
.theme-DotsAndDashes .nivo-directionNav a {
display:block;
width:30px;
height:30px;
background:url(wp-content/uploads/nivo-themes/DotsAndDashes/arrows.png) no-repeat;
text-indent:-9999px;
border:0;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;

.theme-DotsAndDashes:hover .nivo-directionNav a { opacity: 1; }
.theme-DotsAndDashes a.nivo-nextNav {
background-position:-30px 0;
right:15px;
.theme-DotsAndDashes a.nivo-prevNav {
left:15px;
```

For the time being, I now have no arrows whatsoever and can't really understand why that might be...

The other issue concerns the scaling of the thumbnails. At the moment they're centred, but I'm ideally needing for their size to change proportionately according to the number of thumbs in the given gallery...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: provide your html source

Comment: sorry – how do I do that, exactly..?

Comment: http://www.vfxdude.com/testblog/shortcodes/sliders-galleries/nivoslider/

Comment: an example page can be found here: http://dotsanddashes.co.uk/gallery/these-new-puritans-heaven-june-19th-2013/

Answer (score 0):

First thing I noticed is the Failed to load resources error on your arrows.png. So thats why they aren't visible, because they can't be found.
Second, why create an entire theme for nivo when you hardly change anything? Those few minor changes could just as easily be incorperated in your main css as overrides to the original css. This way it's less prone to errors as in forgetting something in your theme or changing something to something else that shouldn't be changed(just giving an example here).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Marius, thanks for your response! The reason I created a custom file, even though it's scarcely been tweaked with, is that I was advised to by the plugin developer having lost all my custom settings for a default theme during a WordPress update. I've got the arrows here: http://dotsanddashes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/nivo-themes/DotsAndDashes/arrows.png though can't get them to show..? Any further help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: I think your problem is, the arrows are basicly white. Your site is white. Do the math :p (sorry for the late response, been busy) Or do you want them as navigation ON the slides? Then I've misunderstood something

EDIT: Ah found it, it's still giving the can't find resource error. Somehow your link to load the arrows is double, so wp-content/uploads/etc and then again /wp-content/uploads/etc I think you hardcoded the link in the css, which isn't necessary apparently.